# Combine rows with matching data into a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for any assistance/feedback for a programming issue I cannot figure out.  I have a table that has multiple customers, and I can "group" those customers 3 different ways based on the data.  What I need to do is find out which customers are actually the same person based on the grouping values.  I simplified what some of the grouping data would look like below for 8 raw customer records.

```
**Var1  Var2    Var3**  
NULL    222     NULL  
NULL    222     444  
NULL    555     333  
NULL    666     333  
NULL    666     777  
111     NULL    333  
111     555     333  
111     666     333
```

And I'm looking for a result that combines all the data from the rows where the values are equal, including those thru a transitive combination like if a = b and b = c then a = c.

For the example above I would expect to see 2 strings (i.e. there are 2 distinct customers) as output from a process:

```
'222, 444'  
'111, 333, 555, 666, 777'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  This requires some sort of recursion or hierarchical processing.

Comment: I don't follow your logic at all.   What is it about the data in your example that tells you there are only two customers?

Comment: Think of the values in the example of a unique Hash value, and I generated the var1 from the customer Name/Email Address, var2 from Name/Street Address, and var3 from Name/Birthdate/Zipcode.  So I see the value 222 in the first 2 records I assume its the same person because both have same Name/Street Address.  One of those records also has 444 for var3 so if I find Hash values of 222 or 444 I can assume its the same customer.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small test on your question, assuming the source table (SO_Test) has columns
ID1 varchar(10), ID2 varchar(10), ID3 , UID uniqueidentifier
below is the SQL script works on MS SQL Server.

At final, you should group by the UID column.[image]

```
declare @cnt int, @cnt_i int = 0, @ID1 varchar(100), @ID2 varchar(100)

--Build up association mapping table
select x.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by ID1) as ROW_NUM
into #temp
from
(
select ID1, ID2
--into #temp
from SO_Test
where (ID1 IS NOT NULL AND ID2 IS NOT NULL)
UNION
select ID1, ID3 
from SO_Test
where (ID1 IS NOT NULL AND ID3 IS NOT NULL)
UNION
select ID2, ID3 
from SO_Test
where (ID2 IS NOT NULL AND ID3 IS NOT NULL)
) x

set @cnt = (select max(ROW_NUM) from #temp)

create table #final
(
    PKID uniqueidentifier,
    [str] varchar(1000)
)

--Scan mapping and put together
while (@cnt > @cnt_i)
begin
    set @cnt_i = @cnt_i + 1

    select  @ID1 = ID1, 
            @ID2 = ID2
    from #temp
    where ROW_NUM = @cnt_i  

    IF not exists (
        select *
        from #final
        where [str] LIKE '%' + @ID1 + '%'
            or [str] LIKE '%' + @ID2 + '%'
    )
    begin
        insert into #final
        select NewID(), @ID1

        if not exists (
            select *
            from #final
            where [str] like '%' + @ID2 + '%'
        )
        begin
            update #final
            set [str] = [str] + ',' + @ID2
            where [str] LIKE '%' + @ID1 + '%'
        end     
    end
    else
    begin
        if not exists (
            select *
            from #final
            where [str] like '%' + @ID2 + '%'
        )
        begin
            update #final
            set [str] = [str] + ',' + @ID2
            where [str] LIKE '%' + @ID1 + '%'
        end
    end
end

--New Code to process single item case
declare @res_cnt int, @res_cnt_i int, @str varchar(1000)
set @res_cnt_i = 0
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by PKID) as ROW_NUM into #temp2 from #final
set @res_cnt = (select max(ROW_NUM) from #temp2)

create table #final_table
(
    [str]   varchar(10)
)

while (@res_cnt > @res_cnt_i)
begin
    set @res_cnt_i = @res_cnt_i + 1

    select @str = [str]
    from #temp2
    where ROW_NUM = @res_cnt_i

    insert into #final_table
    select value from [dbo].[StringToRow_varchar](@str)
end

insert into #final
select NewID(), ID1
from 
(
    select ID1
    from SO_Test
    where (ID1 IS NOT NULL AND ID2 IS NULL AND ID3 IS NULL)
    UNION
    select ID2
    from SO_Test
    where (ID1 IS NULL AND ID2 IS NOT NULL AND ID3 IS NULL)
    UNION
    select ID3 
    from SO_Test
    where (ID1 IS NULL AND ID2 IS NULL AND ID3 IS NOT NULL)
) z
where ID1 not in (select [str] from #final_table)


--View final result
select * from #final

--Update original source table for uniqueID (group by column)
update src
set src.UID = f.PKID
from SO_Test src, #final f
where f.[str] like '%' + src.ID1 + '%'
    or f.[str] like '%' + src.ID2 + '%'
    or f.[str] like '%' + src.ID3 + '%'

select * from SO_Test

drop table #temp
drop table #temp2
drop table #final
drop table #final_table
update SO_Test set [UID] = NULL
```

Here is the new result

[image]

```
CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[StringToRow_varchar]
(
    @input  varchar(2000)
)
RETURNS @temp TABLE 
(
    id int,
    value varchar(100),
    columnName varchar(10)
)
AS
Begin
    declare @after_input varchar(2000) 
    declare @delimiter varchar(2), @i int
    set @i = 0
    set @delimiter = ',' 
    set @after_input = @input + @delimiter

    declare @item varchar(100)

    while (charindex(@delimiter, @after_input) > 0) 
    begin 
        set @i = @i + 1
        set @item = convert(varchar(100), SUBSTRING(@after_input, 1, charindex(@delimiter, @after_input)-1))

        insert into @temp select @i as id, @item, 'Col' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @i)

        set @after_input = SUBSTRING(@after_input, charindex(@delimiter, @after_input) + 1, len(@after_input) - charindex(@delimiter, @after_input) + 1)        
    end
    return 
END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Chjquest, but I don't think it would work if I had a record like Null, 888, Null.  I think your solution picks up the first record in the example (Null, 222, Null) because the 222 also appears in the second record.  But this is very close, thank you.

Comment: I updated the code, it will handle the case like 999, NULL, NULL or NULL, 888, NULL. Simply to exclude it from the collection. But need to create a table function (StringToRow_varchar) to deal with the result. You can then optimize this by yourself.